# How to make a image to store several icons?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to make a image to hold several icons, they are all the same size.

I was wondering if there is a way to see a division every `20px` (my icon size), so I can manage the icons position easily.

Or is there an even better way to manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can just adjust the grid size:

> Edit > Preferences > Guides, Grids & Slices

And activate Snap to Grid

Answer (score 3):

You can add vertical and horizontal guidelines by going to `View` - `New Guide...` I guess that's very annoying.

But: There is an extension to Adobe Photoshop called [Gridmaker2](http://www.andrewingram.net/articles/gridmaker_reboot/), which you could try (the file you need to download is [this one](http://www.andrewingram.net/files/gridmaker-reboot-article/GridMaker2.jsx))

> Installation is easy, just put GridMaker.jsx in your Photoshop\Presets\Scripts directory and load the program, the script will be available in the File/Scripts menu.

Comment: +1 for grid lines. Is this for a web image that will be CSS-positioned?